# How to place a background image in a <div> block and behave as "responsive"

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I have a `background-image` in a  block as seen in the page link below.

I am trying to display the image as follows:

- I want the image to consume more of the page background (irrespective of how much content is in the div block
- I need the image to extend outside the boundaries of the  block it is in
- I want to the image to be responsive

It seems that my image grows and shrinks as I add more content or take content away. Is there anyway to get the image to appear larger than it is (ideally ~90% of viewport width) and retain its 90% size across various screen resolutions?

http://bit.ly/1IgmNKT

Thank you.

Comment: Need a sample code, pls...

Comment: Isn't this a use-case for `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: Interesting @JoshBurgess...I just changed `background-size` from `contain` to `cover` and it works nicely on large screen sizes but then its responsive nature stops working on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: how about:   background-size: 100% auto;

Comment: No problem, I added it as an answer below to make it easier to spot for someone else who might have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 background-size: 100% auto;
```